# Unable to Stream OpenAI Response to Client Using eventsource-parser and Next.js Edge Runtime

Tags: reactjs, next.js, openai-api

I've tried so many things now I've lost track of what I've done, but I can't get the result to stream in the client. No matter what I try, the content is rendered all at once at the end of the stream.

Here's my back-end function:

```js
import { createParser } from "eventsource-parser";

const openAiStream = async (system, prompt) => {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();

    const res = await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_KEY}`
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
            messages: [
                {
                    role: "system",
                    content: system
                },
                {
                    role: "user",
                    content: prompt
                }
            ],
            max_tokens: 150,
            temperature: 0.0,
            stream: true
        })
    });

    if (res.status !== 200) {
        const mess = await res.text();
        throw new Error(mess);
    }

    const stream = new ReadableStream({
        async start(controller) {
            const onParse = (event) => {
                if (event.type === "event") {
                    const data = event.data;

                    if (data === "[DONE]") {
                        controller.close();
                        return;
                    }

                    try {
                        const json = JSON.parse(data);
                        const text = json.choices[0].delta.content;
                        const queue = encoder.encode(text);
                        controller.enqueue(queue);
                    } catch (e) {
                        controller.error(e);
                    }
                }
            };

            const parser = createParser(onParse);

            for await (const chunk of res.body) {
                parser.feed(decoder.decode(chunk));
            }
        }
    });

    return stream;
};

export default openAiStream;
```

And here's my edge handler:

```js
import readRequestBody from "@/lib/api/readRequestBody";
import endent from "endent";
import openAiStream from "@/lib/openAi/openAiStream";

// Use Next.js edge runtime
export const config = {
    runtime: 'edge',
}

export default async function handler(request) {
    try {
        const requestData = await readRequestBody(request);
        const query = requestData.searchTerm.replace(/\n/g, " ");

        const system = endent`
    You are a helpful assistant that answers questions based on a provided body of text.
    Use only the provided text to answer the question. Try not to copy the text word-for-word.
    If you are not certain of the answer, then answer: "Sorry, I can't help you with that."
    `

        const textBody = requestData.chunks.map(c => {
            return c.content + ' ';
        });

        const prompt = `Please answer this query: ${query}\n\n`
            + `Use only the following information:\n\n${textBody}`;

        const stream = await openAiStream(system, prompt);

        return new Response(stream);
    } catch (err) {
        return new Response(`Server error: ${err.message}`, { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

And here's the relevant function in my front-end code:

```js
    const getAnswer = async (chunks) => {
        const body = {
            searchTerm,
            chunks
        };

        const response = await fetch('/api/vsearch/answer', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            const message = await response.text();
            throw new Error(message);
        }

        const stream = response.body;
        const reader = stream.getReader();

        while (true) {
            const { done, value } = await reader.read();

            if (done) {
                break;
            }

            const chunk = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(value);
            setAnswer((prev) => prev + chunk);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Check out the [Vercel chatgpt example](https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/solutions/ai-chatgpt)

Comment: If you're backend returns a text event stream, then you might able to use this react hook: https://github.com/XD2Sketch/react-chat-stream